# Can't properly select multiple objects in Object Mode

Tags: selection-tools

Beginner to Blender here, I'm trying to make a sofa, I finished it and I'd like to parent all my objects but I have a weird dark orange that doesn't work as a selection and I don't know how to rid off.
[image]

Also, when I set parent to Object (Keep Transform), it don't work as 1 object, I can still move alone my cushions.

[image]

Comment: The dark orange means that the objects are all selected, however if you look carefully at the lower image you'll see that the right-hand backrest cushion is hilighted in a lighter orange. That means that it is the active object and is the object that the other ones will follow. I'd suggest holding down Shift and clicking the sofa base to make that be the the active object then CTRL-P to parent the rest to that. You'll still be able to move the other cushions independently as that's by design, but moving the sofa base will move the rest with it.

Comment: If an object has a [parent] it may still be grabbed moved through the user interface. You may lock the position of an object from manual grab.  You may also set the object to by not selectable. You may also [join] meshes.  Its your choice. You may wish to see a tutorial that covers these features or someone here at BSE may have answers fully discussing these features.

Comment: By the way, when you are parenting the cushions, simply use _Object_, you don't have to use _Object (Keep Transform)_ - this only has an effect if the cushions are already parented to a different object and you want to switch the parent from one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

The Parent operation does not group objects. Instead, it makes the last selected object (the active one) act as "Parent", and the other selected objects act as "Children" of the parent. The child objects can move independently, but they always follow the parent object. So, if you move the parent object - all objects will move and you can still move the child objects.